# How to add button within text like ones on Twitter of Instagram app's hash tags

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, uitextview

### Buttons within text like Instagram or Twitter app's

On my iOS app, I need to embed buttons within text like Instagram or Twitter app's do for hash tags within a post.

#### Some detailed requirements are

- buttons triggers iOS native action on "TOUCHN UP INSIDE"
- buttons need to glow on "TOUCH DOWN" like UIButtons
- buttons are NOT web links

#### .link AttribuedString did not work(this is what people say is the solution)

Using .link attribute for AttributedString was closest I got but it had some side effects.

It meets all my requirements but when I long tap the button, iOS show by its UIKit feature a link text over the UITextLabel and the link text is also can be dragged and I do not want those to happen.

Here is what I tried.  I basically added .link attributes and set keyword as URL that I could retried specific keyword on UITextView's delegate method "should interact with URL" and trigger some iOS native code.

```
public extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setKeywordAsLink(keyword: String, fontAttributeForKeyword font: UIFont) {
        guard let url = keyword.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return }

        self.addAttributes([ NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], range: NSString(string: self.string).range(of: keyword))
        self.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: NSString(string: self.string).range(of: keyword))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code off hand but I would not recommend the approach above. You should create a custom UIButton Class  and override the isHighlighted and isSelected functions. Here's a similar example of overriding the isHighlighted from an old project I have. You can add the UIButton as your normally would, just set it to the type of your custom Class (here it would be let button: UIButtonExample!) you can then add regular IBActions for TouchUpInside and TouchDown if you'd like.

```
class UIButtonExample: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //set up origin formatting here
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = .black
    }


    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isHighlighted {
                //pressed on
                self.animatePress()
            } else {
                //unpressed
                self.animateHome()
            }
        }
    }

    func animatePress() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }
    }

    func animateHome() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I embed this within text? like inside UITextLabel or UITextView?